# Using group_by and count in user defined functions

Tags: r, dplyr

I have created function using the `group_by` and `count` but I don't get the results desired...

```
count_func <- function(groupvar, outcome){
  mtcars %>% 
    group_by({{groupvar}}) %>% 
    count({{groupvar}}, {{outcome}})
}

count_func("vs", "am")
```

This is what I desire to get

```
mtcars %>% group_by(vs) %>% count(vs, am)
```

Comment: i dont keep up but i think the current way to do this is to add `groupvar <- rlang::sym(groupvar); outcome <- rlang::sym(outcome)` to your function. also note you can't do `{{rlang::sym(groupvar)}}` for short

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dplyr::count()` instead

```
mtcars %>%  
  count(vs, am) 

  vs am  n
1  0  0 12
2  0  1  6
3  1  0  7
4  1  1  7
```

And your function works if you remove the ""

```
count_func <- function(groupvar, outcome){
  mtcars %>% 
    group_by({{groupvar}}) %>% 
    count({{groupvar}}, {{outcome}})
}

count_func(vs, am)

# A tibble: 4 × 3
# Groups:   vs [2]
     vs    am     n
  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1     0     0    12
2     0     1     6
3     1     0     7
4     1     1     7
```

Comment: you can also remove the `{{groupvar}}` from the `count` function call :-)

Comment: the most concise version of this function is `count_func <- \(...) count(mtcars, ...)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to continue passing column names as strings `.data` is your friend. Additionally, I would also include another argument (`dat`) in the function to pass data.

```
library(dplyr)

count_func <- function(dat, groupvar, outcome){
  dat %>% 
    count(.data[[groupvar]], .data[[outcome]])
}

count_func(mtcars, "vs", "am")

#  vs am  n
#1  0  0 12
#2  0  1  6
#3  1  0  7
#4  1  1  7
```